PWA: Add user defined shortcuts to homescreen
In the manifest.json of an PWA I can define shortcuts but if all of the shortcuts are available depends on the Browser an OS. Chrome on Android only shows the first three shortcuts. So some won't be available.
Is there a way that my PWA can give the user the possibility to add custom shortcuts to the homescreen?

I assume you could probably dynamically serve a manifest file if, for example, the user is logged in. I'm not sure if/when these changes would be pulled, though. The user may need to remove and re-add the PWA, and caching may also pose a problem.

There is no user login or any kind of user identification. The app has several functions I like to give the user the ability to chose which function is important for them and create a shortcut on their home screen so they don't have to open the app and navigate to the function but instead click on the home screen shortcut

You may be able to do it by setting cookies or something similar, but I’d assume that’d be less reliable. I’d need to implement it to give you a 100% answer though.

Even I would use cookies an/ or an user login and return a user/cookie specific manifest file, this wouldn't help me with the Problem that Chrome on Android only shows no more than three shortcuts. But I want the user to create as many shortcuts as they need

I mean, that's an android/chrome limitation- not a ton you can do there...

Yes I know. That's why I asked if PWAs have the ability to create custom shortcuts on the home screen
